# zombiejs (2.0.0-alpha30) + mochajs (1.17.1) on node 0.10.26

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, zombie.js

I started working through a book's example code and had the bright idea to update the libraries (node included, from 0.8 -> 0.10). Now there is some breakage & I get this error:

```
1) Todos Todo creation form should allow to create a todo:
 Uncaught Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
  at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
  at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
```

I've commented out the assertions to try and locate the issue. It seems like it's a zombiejs centric issue but I'm not sure how to verify that because there are many modules installed as dependencies. There are 10 other tests that pass with most using the login function so I eliminated that from the probabilities. I tried to just post the necessary code snippets. I can provide more if this isn't enough detail. I've found a few stackoverflow posts with this error but the solutions didn't apply. If it turns out to be a zombie issue I will post something on their bug site.

```
it('should allow to create a todo', login(function (browser, done) {
        Browser.visit('http:localhost:3000/todos/new', function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            //browser
            //    .fill('textarea[name="what]', 'Test todo')
             //   .pressButton('input[type="submit"]', function (err) {
              //      if (err) throw err;
                    //browser.assert.pathname('/todos', 'should be redirected to /todos');

                    //finish assertions
                    //browser.assert.elements('#todo-list tr.todo', 1, 'To-Do list should contain 1 item');

                //});
        });
    }));
```

The main entries in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "union": "0.4.0",
  "flatiron": "0.3.x",
  "plates": "0.4.x",
  "node-static": "0.7.x",
  "nano":"5.x.x",
  "flatware-cookie-parser" : "0.1.x" ,
  "flatware-session": "0.1.x"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "mocha" : "latest",
  "zombie": "latest"
},
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you try enabling debugging of node net by `export NDOE_DEBUG=net` to see where the error is thrown? since it uses `request` in `zombie.js`, you can use `export NODE_DEBUG=request` as well

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it was a stupid user error. I forgot to tell mocha the test was "done();". I added done to the end of the test case...tests are working as expected. Thanks!